# Python - While Loops so frustrating pls explain, is infinite loop condition is always true

Tags: python, while-loop

```
num=int(input("Enter a number between 10 and 20."))
    while num<10 or num>20:
        num1=int(input("Enter a number between 10 and 20."))
        if 10<num<20:
        break
print("Well done!")
```

The loop is infinite cannot escape. Output is always (num1) not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The loop is infinite cannot escape. Output is always (num1) not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The loop is infinite because it tests the value of `num` (which we already know is outside the acceptable range when we enter the loop).

But `num` does not change within the loop - the input only modifies `num1`.